# Creating decision tree

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, decision-tree

I have a csv file (298 rows and 24 columns) and i want to create a decision tree to predict the column "salary". I have downloaded tree package and added via library function.

But when i try to create the decision tree:

```
model<-tree(salary~.,data)
```

I get the error like below:

```
 *Error in tree(salary ~ ., data) : 
  factor predictors must have at most 32 levels*
```

What is wrong with that? Data is as follows:

```
      Name bat hit homeruns runs
1   Alan Ashby 315  81        7   24
2  Alvin Davis 479 130       18   66
3 Andre Dawson 496 141       20   65
...
team position putout assists errors
1 Hou.        C    632      43     10
2 Sea.       1B    880      82     14
3 Mon.       RF    200      11      3
salary league87 team87
1    475        N   Hou.
2    480        A   Sea.
3    500        N   Chi.
```

And its the value of str(data):

'data.frame':   263 obs. of  24 variables:
 $ Name                     : Factor w/ 263 levels "Al Newman","Alan Ashby",..: 2 7 8 10 6 1 13 11 9 3 ...

$ bat                      : int  315 479 496 321 594 185 298 323 401 574 ...

$ hit                      : int  81 130 141 87 169 37 73 81 92 159 ...

$ homeruns                 : int  7 18 20 10 4 1 0 6 17 21 ...

$ runs                     : int  24 66 65 39 74 23 24 26 49 107 ...

$ runs.batted              : int  38 72 78 42 51 8 24 32 66 75 ...

$ walks                    : int  39 76 37 30 35 21 7 8 65 59 ...

$ years.in.major.leagues   : int  14 3 11 2 11 2 3 2 13 10 ...

$ bats.during.career       : int  3449 1624 5628 396 4408 214 509 341 5206 4631 ...

$ hits.during.career       : int  835 457 1575 101 1133 42 108 86 1332 1300 ...

$ homeruns.during.career   : int  69 63 225 12 19 1 0 6 253 90 ...

$ runs.during.career       : int  321 224 828 48 501 30 41 32 784 702 ...

$ runs.batted.during.career: int  414 266 838 46 336 9 37 34 890 504 ...

$ walks.during.career      : int  375 263 354 33 194 24 12 8 866 488 ...

$ league                   : Factor w/ 2 levels "A","N": 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 ...

$ division                 : Factor w/ 2 levels "E","W": 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 ...

$ team                     : Factor w/ 24 levels "Atl.","Bal.",..: 9 21 14 14 16 14 10 1 7 
8 ...

$ position                 : Factor w/ 23 levels "1B","1O","23",..: 10 1 20 1 22 4 22 22 13 22 ...

$ putout                   : int  632 880 200 805 282 76 121 143 0 238 ...

$ assists                  : int  43 82 11 40 421 127 283 290 0 445 ...

$ errors                   : int  10 14 3 4 25 7 9 19 0 22 ...

$ salary                   : num  475 480 500 91.5 750 ...

$ league87                 : Factor w/ 2 levels "A","N": 2 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 ...

$ team87                   : Factor w/ 24 levels "Atl.","Bal.",..: 9 21 5 14 16 13 10 1 7 8 ...

Comment: you should provide at least few rows of your `salary` and `data` variables so we know what are we working with.

Comment: It would be more useful to see `str(data)`, as then we could see which variables are factors and how many levels they have. I'm guessing that you included in the "Name" variable in your model though - which you shouldn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is almost certainly that you're including the name variable in your model, as it has too many factor levels. I would also remove it a methodological standpoint but this probably isn't the place for that discussion. Try:

```
train <- data
train$Name <- NULL
model<-tree(salary~.,train)
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your `salary` is a **factor** vector, while you are trying to perform a **regression**, so it should be a **numbers** vector. Simply convert you `salary` to numeric, and it should work just fine. For more details read the library's help:

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tree/tree.pdf

> **Usage**
>
> tree(formula, data, weights, subset, na.action = na.pass,
>   control = tree.control(nobs, ...), method = "recursive.partition",
>   split = c("deviance", "gini"), model = FALSE, x = FALSE, y = TRUE, wts
>   = TRUE, ...)
>
> **Arguments**
>
> *formula* A formula expression. The left-hand-side (response) should be either a **numerical vector when a
>   regression tree will be ﬁtted** or a factor, when a classiﬁcation tree
>   is produced. The right-hand-side should be a series of numeric or
>   factor variables separated by +; there should be no interaction terms.
>   Both . and - are allowed: regression trees can have offset terms.
>   (...)

Depending on what exactly is stored in your `salary` variable, the conversion can be less or more tricky, but this should generaly work:

```
salary = as.numeric(levels(salary))[salary]
```

**EDIT**

As pointed out in the comment, the actual error corresponds to the `data` variable, so if it is a numerical data, it could also be converted to numeric to solve the issue, if it has to be a factor you will need another model or reduce the number of levels. You can also convert these factors to the numerical format by hand (by for example defining as many binary features as you have levels), but this can lead to the exponential growth of your input space.

**EDIT2**

It seems that you have to first decide what you are trying to model. You are trying to predict salary, but based on what? It seems that your data consists of players' records, then their names are for sure wrong type of data to use for this prediction (in particular - it is probably causing the 32 levels error). You should remove all the columns from the `data` variable which should not be used for building a prediction. I do not know what is the exact aim here (as there is no information regarding it in the question), so I can only guess that you are trying to predict the person's salary based on his/her stats, so **you should remove** from the input data: **players' names**, players' teams and obviously salaries (as predicting X using X is not a good idea ;)).

Comment: The error specifically refers to predictors, not the response. There is a general limit in `tree` (and `rpart` I believe) that factors cannot have more than 32 levels. It may actually be intended to be a factor, but has too many levels. Can't tell without their data.

Comment: i have converted the salary: salary <- data[ , "salary"] and i've tried again: model<-tree(salary,data). But i get another error: Error in formula.default(object, env = baseenv()) : invalid formula. Do i have to convert salary in data self? Or something else?